# Eslint no-return-assing and no-param-reassign error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, coding-style, eslint

```
const someId = data.id;
                values.some_id = someId;
                values.updateParams.map(
                    params => params.some_another_id = someId,
                );
```

In the above code, eslint is throwing some error and won't be able to understand those.
Here I added the screenshots of the error.

[image]
[image]

Comment: [no-return-assign](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-return-assign), [no-param-reassign](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-param-reassign). The docs seem pretty clear - you are both assignment on return in `params.serviceable_port_pair_id = someId` and changing `values`, too.

Comment: Please do not post text as images. You can easily copy and paste the error messages. You only make it hard for people to copy the messages and hard for SO to properly index your questions so it can be found by others with the same problem. Also you omitted the surrounding function definition which is relevant for the error message.

Comment: Also explanations including examples for eslint rules can be found here: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/

Comment: Thanks, I should have walk through the docs first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const someId = data.id;
values.some_id = someId;
values.updateParams.map(
    params => ({ ...params,  serviceable_port_pair_id: someId,})
);
```

you are supposed to return the Object, how it should look like, but not mutate the parameter inside the arrow function

and for the first error message. The insutructions couldnt be clearer. You shouldnt reassign already defined params